# Are injuries from Assault more Severe than those Sustained During Martial arts Practice?

Tags: self-defense, sparring, injury, streetfight

When I asked [my previous question regarding injury rates in martial arts practice and assault](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/for-what-martial-arts-is-the-chance-of-being-injured-while-training-less-than-th), some users pointed out (quite rightly) that it didn't take account of the severity of injuries sustained.

So, this question is to go with the other one in order to give a balanced view of the effects of training in martial arts on your chances of injury.

Obviously, this does not take into account other potential health benefits of martial arts. However, it will give an idea of injury severity.  Again, let's take the United Kingdom, partly because that's where I live, but mostly because if we take the United States, gun violence eclipses all other injury statistics.

**According to the UK Police, less than 50% of assaults actually caused injury at all.**

See the graph under point 3: Violent Crime [Crime in England and Wales: year ending December 2019](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/crimeandjustice/bulletins/crimeinenglandandwales/yearendingdecember2019)

But let's ignore these (UK law has a very broad definition of assault) and just look at those where some injury was caused.

This is the minimum type of injury that is classed as Actual Bodily Harm:

- The loss or breaking of a tooth or teeth
- Extensive or multiple bruising
- A displaced, broken nose
- Minor fractures of bones
- Minor (but not superficial) cuts requiring medical treatment
- A recognised psychiatric disorder

[Wikipedia for reference who in turn cite the Crown Prosecution Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault_occasioning_actual_bodily_harm)

How do these compare to the minimum types of injury RECORDED in a martial arts dojo?

Comment: I am unclear why this is relevant at all. What are you trying to solve by this?  Also,  there is no control group of just normal injuries.  Note that training martial art could decrease the risk and/or the seriousness of normal injury.

Comment: @Sardathrion What is a 'Normal injury' and why would it be a suitable control group for this?  I am trying to establish which martial arts increase the danger of injury and which decrease the danger of injury.  Finding the ones that decrease the danger of injury will be hard (because injuries in assault are rare)  but finding those that increase the danger of injury should be easy by looking at injury rates while training.  We could look at the effect of learning breakfalls on injury rates too I suppose, falling over is common enough.

Comment: Variation in style,  school,  and teacher might be more significant than per art. Also, competition will skew the statistics.

Comment: True enough. But that is no reason to ignore what information we do have.

Comment: The overriding injury concerns when being attacked are things like death, permanent impairment, or long hospitalization. I fail to see how a comparison of the minimum legal definition of assault in the UK and the minimum injury report criteria for a martial arts school is relevant to those major concerns.

Comment: Sorry I should have made that clear. There are different kinds of vocabulary used in uk courts. Assault is any non consential contact, actual bodily harm is minor injury caused by assault but still serious enough to justify a longer sentence. Grievous bodily harm is a step more serious than actual bodily harm and covers anything short of murder. Sexual assault is measured on a different scale. So while we could look at any of these sentence catagories separately this is the minimum we will have data for.

Comment: Needless to say thats a bad place to stop, but it is a good place to start looking.

Comment: How do we put this question out of it's misery? Minus 4 for three and half years.

Comment: @thatgirlisfunny I could delete it. But I think that the fact that the question is negative rated is important in it's own right because it shows that martial artists have a hostility to the idea that might sustain worse injuries in training than in a self defence situation.  It shows a remarkable level of irrationality.

Comment: Fighting back suggests injury is possible. Don't you think it's important to learn how to fight when injured? It's unlikely that an assailant will just give up. If you break your hand punching someone, you can still elbow or kick. I don't understand your question, so I will respectfully bow out of this conversation with you, Huw.

Comment: @HuwEvans, of course broken bones & noses and concussions COULD happen during training, but a 10-20-second fight on the street, even without guns and knives, could of course easily result in multiple punches to the face, lost teeth, broken jaw, and hitting your head then multiple people stomping on you when you fall down. Have you seriously even seen, in training, more than one hard strike do damage along these lines without the match then being stopped?

Comment: @AmorphousBlob Of course not, but I have seen concussion, broken noses etc.  That is why there are two questions.  One about frequency and the other about severity.  This one is just about severity.  It may be that damage from assault results from more serious but less frequent injury.  I don't know which is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Legally speaking, in most states, you are never physically injured from any assault.  (In other states, assault is the same as battery).

https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/assault

If you meant battery, then no - there's nothing to suggest anything that happens criminally is any more or less severe than MA practice.  Severe injuries can happen - by accident - during practice.  Some forms of illegal battery - eg, spitting - induce no physical injuries at all.

Comment: This was a UK question. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

First off, I'd like to see the link providing proof of this statement:

> According to the UK Police, less than 50% of assaults actually caused
> injury at all.

Secondly, assault is unfriendly, angry and criminal. If you are injured in your dojo, hopefully, you are friends or in some kind of agreeable relationship with the person you are sparring or training with.

To be specific, I would say that yes, in the UK, injuries from assault are traumatizing and more severe than injuries that occur in the dojo.

No, I do not have a link proving that.

Comment: https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/crimeandjustice/bulletins/crimeinenglandandwales/yearendingdecember2019

See the graph under point 3: Violent crime

Comment: Lol! Downvote! Thanks for the link. It still sounds like a silly question. But I'm an outsider to questions about legalities, etc.

Comment: Since you provided the link, I upvoted your question.

Comment: it's not personal.  I just don't think someone seeking an answer is likely to find that response useful.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the UK maintains the original/traditional definitions of "Assault" (a threat or attempt to inflict physical harm or unwanted physical contact) and "Battery" (actually *committing* the act in question), rather than having joined them together.  As such, waving a knife while shouting "I'm gonna gut ya" at someone constitutes Assault, even if the individuals involved maintain their 2 meters of social distancing...